# QGIS GDAL driver error

Tags: qgis, gdal, error, batch

I'm unable to complete processing in the Processing Modeler due to the following GDAL Error:

```
2019-01-21T10:47:12     CRITICAL    Could not create raster output E:\QGIS\QGIS_Projects\GDALTEST: GDAL provider Cannot load GDAL driver 
2019-01-21T10:47:12     CRITICAL    Error encountered while running Reclassify by table
```

Here are the settings:

[image]

[image]

Using QGIS version 3.4.3

Comment: I get the same error when trying to use Reclassify by table in Batch Processing